# Determining the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}$ with variables

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I figure out the following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}$$

I always seem to get that the limit is zero but it isn't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use $(x^3-a^3)=(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)$

Comment: You need to show us your working : we will tell you what is wrong

Answer (score 3):

One may use derivative definition
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}=(x^3)'\Big|_{x=a}=3a^2$$
or using identity
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)}{x-a}=3a^2$$
even l'Hospital rule works here
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{3x^2}{1}=3a^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a+h$.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(a+h)^3-a^3}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3}h=\lim_{h\to0}(3a^2+3ah+h^2).$$

You can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

In the numerator, you have a difference of two cubes.
$$x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)$$

Simply rewrite the limit using the factored form.

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a} \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{(x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)}{x-a}$$
Now, just cancel out $x-a$ and simplify.

$$\lim_{x \to a} x^2+xa+a^2 = a^2+a(a)+a^2 = 3a^2$$